# Removing the CENTER element from a JPanel using BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, constraints, components

Is there any way of removing the `Component` added to the `CENTER` of a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`, without having to reference the `Component` itself?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Something like this?

```
BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout)panel.getLayout();
panel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));
```

Comment: Cool. Had to modify it a bit, but it worked.
Used it in this fashion: 
myPanel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: You're both missing the closing parenthesis for the remove function ;)

Comment: Ensure you you call Container.validate() after you change the components to signal layout manager to recalculate the positions of the components being displayed. In your example it would be panel.validate();

Comment: Can someone explain where exactly you put this code or how to use it.

Comment: i get "incompatible types: LayoutManager cannot be converted to BorderLayout" error message. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably best if you post a new question along with your code, it might be a slightly different scenario