# Java AWT: Clean / Remove a container panel

Tags: java, awt, jpanel

Java AWT: Clean / Remove a container panel

I am new to Java AWT, and I'm wanting to do an exercise for college.

This would be the code:

```
public class Panel0 extends JPanel {

     //...     

     private void createMyLayout(bool test) {


         this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Panel1(test));

     }

     //...
}


public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1(bool test){

        super(new GridLayout(1,4));

        if(breed!= Breed.ZOMBIE) 
            add(new Panel2("helow 1 test"));
        else
            add(new Panel2("helow 2 test"));

    }

}

public class Panel2 extends JPanel{

      public Panel2(String myText){
          super(new BorderLayout());
          add(new JLabel(myText));
       }    
}
```

When you call the method "createMyLayout" I need to delete the previous layout and recreate it with new data, but do not get it done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve width this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759321/removing-the-center-element-from-a-jpanel-using-borderlayout):

```
BorderLayout layout = panel.getLayout();
panel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));
```

Comment: remove() removes a single component.  removeAll() removes all components.

Comment: @donnyton (I know very little of awt and swing) yes, but the method ´removeAll´   erased the entire layout, and I just needed to clear the center. if I delete everything with ´removeAll´not working. may be that this bad example, the code is too big to put it all

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's Swing. You can use the method removeAll in the JPanel0 before add new content on it.

Comment: Can I only clean the `BorderLayout.CENTER`?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually javax.swing, not java.awt.

Also, your question is rather confusing.  You say you want to remove a "layout" but java actually has a Layout class that's not what you're talking about.  You want to remove COMPONENTS.

```
myPanel.removeAll(); //removes all the stuff inside
```

will do the trick.  I'd recommend renaming some of your stuff so you don't get confused between Layouts, Panels, and Components.

Comment: Can I only clean the `BorderLayout.CENTER`?