# How to remove a specific element from a JPanel using BorderLayout/GroupLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, grouplayout, border-layout

I need to remove the `Component` in the `Center` of the `JPanel`, but after some tries no prevail.

I tried the method here:

[Removing the CENTER element from a JPanel using BorderLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759321/removing-the-center-element-from-a-jpanel-using-borderlayout)

But the answer's method produces a compile time error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from LayoutManager to BorderLayout
```

Am I interpreting the answer wrong?

In addition, I am also curious if I can update just a single component from a GroupLayout. Could somebody tell me how to do it?

EDIT: @mre: Here's the code:

```
BorderLayout layout = panel.getLayout();
panel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));
```

Which is basically the same as in the link.

Thank you all!

Comment: please provide relevant code.

Comment: Are you sure that your panel has a BorderLayout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to downcast the layout manager to BorderLayout :

```
BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) panel.getLayout();
```

But if you know which component is in the center, you can just remove it :

```
panel.add(myComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
...
panel.remove(myComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this before, and I just found that there's another error which led me to believe that this solution leads to a NullPointerException. Now it's better:)  p.s. The second solution is great. Does that also apply to GroupLayout?