# How do I get thet components that are in a particular layout location in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, border-layout

I have a `JFrame` that uses the `BorderLayout`. How do I get all the components that are in the left or the right or in any other location of this `JFrame`?

Comment: This should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759321/removing-the-center-element-from-a-jpanel-using-borderlayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @brano suggested, you can access those components via the `LayoutManager` of your `JFrame`'s `contentPane`.

For exemple, assuming that you want to get the component that is located on `BorderLayout.WEST` (and that your `JFrame` is called `frame`), you could do:

```
final BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) frame.getContentPane().getLayout();
final Component west = layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.WEST);
```

One remark, though: the `getLayoutComponent` method doesn't belong to `LayoutManager`: thus, you **have to** know and be sure that your `layout` is an actual `BorderLayout`.