# Java - Redrawing a component from within a separate component

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, oop

I'm very new to GUI programming in Java and have come up against a problem where changes in one component cause another component (not a parent or child or grandparent or grandchild etc.) to have to be redrawn. More specifically, I have a window as a `winGUI` (a subclass of `JFrame`) with a BorderLayout contentPane, the CENTER of which contains a component with the following method which runs when the component is clicked:

```
winGUI window = (winGUI)(getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());
window.updatePanel(panelContent);
```

(I suspect there's a much better way of retrieving the window, so that would be good to know.)

The class definition of winGUI is as follows

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class winGUI extends JFrame {
    private UIController userInterface;
    private JPanel content;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new winGUI();
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public winGUI() {
        super("Window");
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setResizable(false);
        content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        userInterface = new UIController();
        content.add(userInterface.getCenter(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(userInterface.getPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        setContentPane(content);
        setLocation(0, 0);
    }

    public void updatePanel(PanelContent panelContent) {
        userInterface.buildPanel(panelContent);
        content.add(userInterface.getPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

}
```

And here are the important bits of the UIController class:

```
private JPanel sidePanel;

public UIController() {
    buildPanel(null);
}

public void buildPanel(PanelContent panelContent) {
    sidePanel = new JPanel();
    sidePanel.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220));
    sidePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
    sidePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 500));
    if (panelContent != null) {
        sidePanel.add(new JLabel(panelContent.getLabel()));
    }
}

public JPanel getPanel() {
    return sidePanel;
}
```

After calling `userInterface.buildPanel(panelContent)` from within the `updatePanel` method, I was expecting the panel to change because the getPanel() method passes by reference, and so the component added to `content` when the window was created should be updated as well as `sidePanel` because they reference the same object. However, this did not happen, so I tried adding

```
content.add(userInterface.getPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
userInterface.getPanel().repaint();
this.repaint();
```

to the end of the `updatePanel` method, but to no avail.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: *"I suspect there's a much better way of retrieving the window"* - [`SwingUtilities.windowForComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent(java.awt.Component)) - But I would question the use of this.  A better solution be to pass some kind of manager/controller down through the component hierarchy which described the actions which child components are allowed to perform

Comment: You may need to invalidate the component hierarchy in order to force it to update it's layouts.  Try calling `revalidate` followed by `repaint`

Comment: I tried using revalidate and had some strange results. (The code in my original question is simplified; in my actual program the side panel has `JPanel`s containing `JLabel`s, `JButton`s and `JTextField`s.) One `JTextField` is the only thing I see drawn, but buttons are drawn as I hover over where they should be (and remain when I move the mouse away) and most of the other `JTextField` appears if I click where it should be. The `JLabel`s still don't appear. It looks like some bug in swing but I don't see how this could have been missed as I'm not doing anything unusual.

Comment: No, it's not a bug in Swing, it's either a threading issue, null layout issue or the fact that panel hasn't recognized the fact that it needs to be laid out. Without a a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, it's all guess work. Note: This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've fixed it now; I had to [remove the old panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759321/removing-the-center-element-from-a-jpanel-using-borderlayout) from `content`'s WEST before calling `buildPanel`, adding the updated panel to `content` and calling `validate()` or `revalidate()` and `repaint()`. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (creating your own Swing like listener) to pass the event to `winGui` that it should update it's panel.

```
interface SomeUpdateListener {
     public void onUpdate(PanelContent panelContent);
}
```

Then have `winGui` be such a listener:

```
public class winGUI extends JFrame implements SomeUpdateListener
    ...
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(PanelContent panelContent) {
        userInterface.buildPanel(panelContent);
        content.add(userInterface.getPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        // Fix for your last issue I believe
        this.revalidate();  // Pretty sure this is what's needed in your case
        this.repaint(); // redraws them
    }
```

I have no idea what the custom component actually use to call updatePanel is or how it works, but let's assume it's called `SomeCustomComponent` with roughly the following code now:

```
public class SomeCustomComponent extends JComponent {
    private SomeUpdateListener listener;
    public SomeCustomComponent(SomeUpdateListener someListener) {
         this.listener = someListener;
    }
    ...
    private void timeToMakeThatPanelContentUpdate() {
         PanelContent newContent = createNewPanelContents();
         listener.onUpdate(newContent);
    }
    ...
```

So now with this new "listener" type, you don't have a direct circular like reference between your parent (or eventually parent I suppose here...), and the child component in your application code.

Note I added in a couple lines to fix the last issue of the panel not updating with the latest contents in the `onUpdate()` method.

```
this.revalidate(); // Pretty sure this is what's needed in your case
this.repaint();
```

Also if the panel you are creating is not actually any different through some GUI component combinations, but instead only different from the information it displays, then perhaps you should just pass data that represents what the preexisting GUI components should now display.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would have passed the window object to the constructor but it already has 4 parameters and will possibly acquire more as I continue working on it. Revalidate was one of the key elements I was missing, the other was [removing the old panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759321/removing-the-center-element-from-a-jpanel-using-borderlayout) before rebuilding it and adding it. Sorry I can't up-vote your answer; I don't have enough points //\\(-_-)//\\

Comment: @Zyxl No problem. You can always get (I think) most of your initial points through going to Help -> Tour and scrolling through the page to the bottom. This should be enough points to allow you to add comments on people's questions at least.