# How do you return the JPanel in the center of a JFrame using a BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, return, jpanel

I have so far found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759321/removing-the-center-element-from-a-jpanel-using-borderlayout#_=_) helpful.

But I couldn't get it working, especially this part `.getLayoutComponent`.

This is how I want the method to look in the class:

```
public JPanel getCentrePanel() {

    return [CENTER PANEL WOULD BE RETURNED HERE];
}
```

Comment: this should be work `return yourContainer.getLayout().getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));`

Comment: I'm not sure if I have a container, my JFrame (frmAdmin) is a BorderLayout and I have the panel I want to return in the centre (BorderLayout.CENTER).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the layout from the content pane of your `JFrame`.

```
BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) frmAdmin.getContentPane().getLayout();
return (JPanel) layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for the quick responses, but I couldn't get this to work
as shown here: https://gyazo.com/54942f9dffa53261214b2167c0d3fb87

Error 1: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from LayoutManager to BorderLayout"

Error 2: "The method getContentPane() is undefined for the type AdminView"

Error 3: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Component to JPanel"

Comment: Cast layout to `BorderLayout`.

Comment: Huge thanks, I got it all working now, should have told you earlier. Really saved my course work there, cheers!